# Rendering graduated symbology for dynamically called layers using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, layers, symbology, arcgis-pro

I am trying to render graduated symbology for dynamically called layers using arcpy in ArcGIS Pro 2.7.  The first code block below adds the layers to the map, but when I try to call these layers and customize the symbology I receive errors as included below in the 2nd and 3rd code block.

Is the problem that I am not calling the layers correctly?

#List features from Results feature dataset,
#Makes feature layer from features, adds feature layers to map

```
m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
for ds in datasets:
    ResultList= arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "ALL", ds)
    for fc in ResultList:
        OutFile = os.path.join(wkspc, str(fc))
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, fc, None, None)
        lf = arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile(fc, OutFile)
```

#render graduated symbology for the layers referenced above;

Line 2: for lyr in l():     TypeError: 'layer' object is not callable

```
l= m.listLayers()[0]
for lyr in l():  
  if lyr.isFeatureLayer:
     sym = lyr.symbology
     if hasattr(sym, 'renderer'):
       if sym.renderer.type == "GraduatedSymbolsRenderer":
#modify graduated symbol renderer
        sym.renderer.classificationField = "Total_Deli"
        sym.renderer.breakCount = 6
        sym.renderer.minimumSymbolSize = 10
        sym.renderer.maximumSymbolSize = 25
    
        lyr.symbology = sym
```

Different approach--

Line 2: sym = l.symbology     AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'symbology'

```
    l = m.listLayers()[0]
    sym = l.symbology  
    if hasattr(sym,'renderer'):
        if sym.renderer.type == "GraduatedSymbolsRenderer":
            sym.renderer.classificationField = "Total_Deli"
            sym.renderer.breakCount = 6
            sym.renderer.minimumSymbolSize = 10
            sym.renderer.maximumSymbolSize = 25
    
            l.symbology = sym
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

Edited casting m.listLayers to variable l, just directly used m.listlayers (line 1). Also needed to utilize the sym.updateRenderer function to change the layer symbology. Code below.

```
  for lyr in m.listLayers():
      if lyr.isFeatureLayer:
          sym = lyr.symbology
          if hasattr(sym, 'renderer'):
              if sym.renderer.type == "SimpleRenderer":
                  sym.updateRenderer('GraduatedSymbolsRenderer')
                  sym.renderer.classificationField = "Total_Deli"
                  sym.renderer.breakCount = 6
                  sym.renderer.minimumSymbolSize = 1
                  sym.renderer.maximumSymbolSize = 10
    
                  lyr.symbology = sym
```